# python и баллы twitch

Tags: python, twitch

Естьtwitch награда, надо чтобы если пользователь приобрёл её, python код это зафиксировал и желательно ещё и одобрил её.

Вот всё что я нашёл:
https://pytwitchapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html - api twitch 
https://riptutorial.com/twitch/example/6047/python - другой способ к нему обратится.

Но ничего даже близко похожего на мой запрос. Заранее спасибо за помощь.